# Overflow makes item in absolute position disapearing

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I have a specific timeline with several month that can go beyond its container and no scroll is available. The month are inside a div but are visually positionned on top of it with relative/absolute combo.If I decide to do overflow: "auto" to see the last items of the timeline then the month disappears.

here is my code:

```
const Timeline = () => {

 const monthsBetween = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec', 'jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul'];

  return (
      <div style={{ width: `${monthsBetween.length * 150}px` }}>
        <div style={{ width: `${monthsBetween.length * 150}px`, border: '1px solid lightgrey', height: '50px', position: 'relative', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          {monthsBetween.map((month, index) => (
            <div key={index} >
              <p style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '-35px', left: `calc(150px * ${index + 1})`, transform: 'translateX(-50%)' }}>{month}</p>
              <div style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                top: '0',
                left: `calc(150px * ${index + 1})`,
                borderLeft: "1px solid lightgray",
                height: "50px",
              }} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
```

I know that the problem is in the position with CSS,I can still see the bottom of the month appearing but I cannot not find a way to fix it, here it looks without overflow:

[image]

And here with the overflow:

[image]

And it still does not scroll on the right.

EDIT: after adding:

- overflow:"auto", padding: "35px 0"
  on the first div I can now see the month and the scrollbar, but it is still not scrolling.

Comment: Have you inapected the rendered HTML - is it what you expect in terms of widths? And when you decide to put in overflow where do you put it?

Comment: @AHaworth I did and yes it is what I expect in term of width and as a confirmation I can add the overflow on the card that contains all this code and I can scroll freely until the end of the timeline (but the entire card which is not what I want). And for the overflow I put it the first div. EDIT: I added this also     padding: 35px 0; on the first div and now I can see the month and the scrollbar but it does not scroll

Answer (score 0):

the

> overflow: auto

will set scroll-x and scroll-y if they are needed.
But you just want the x, so, I think that this will be a better solution:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: visible;
```

Comment: Nop does not do the trick sorry

Answer (score 0):

After several try a padding needed to be added to the first div and the width needed to be removed to allow the scrolling:

```
const Timeline = () => {

 const monthsBetween = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec', 'jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul'];

  return (
      <div style={{ overFlowX: 'auto', padding: '35px 0' }}>  // <-- Here
        <div style={{ width: `${monthsBetween.length * 150}px`, border: '1px solid lightgrey', height: '50px', position: 'relative', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          {monthsBetween.map((month, index) => (
            <div key={index} >
              <p style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '-35px', left: `calc(150px * ${index + 1})`, transform: 'translateX(-50%)' }}>{month}</p>
              <div style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                top: '0',
                left: `calc(150px * ${index + 1})`,
                borderLeft: "1px solid lightgray",
                height: "50px",
              }} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
```